# Mongoose, populate boolean variable if ObjectId in array of document field returned from query

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

So I have a User model and a Post model. A Use case is that a User can Like a Post.

The Post Schema conatins array of ObjectID that I have named "likers" (User objects that like post)

I want to write a query that returns all posts but each post has an additional "liked" field that is boolean based on if logged in user objectid is in "likers" array.

My code I am trying:

```
router.get("/posts", function(req, res, next) {
  Posts.find({})
    .then(posts => {
      posts = posts.map(post => {
        // How to write this so it works
        // test if req.user._id in likers which is Schema type [ObjectID]
        post.liked = req.user && (post.likers.indexOf(req.user._id) > -1);
        return post;
      });
      res.json(posts);
    })
    .catch(errorHandler(res));
});
```

Comment: So you're trying to rewrite your code? Because it seems like what you already have works.

Comment: No I can't get it to work. Probably something to do with comparing ObjectID's that I can't figure out.

Comment: Maybe `post.likers.map(String).indexOf(req.user.id)` which basically should convert your array to Strings and compare it with the String id.

Comment: I've never done this before but maybe  a cleaner approach would be to use [`aggregate`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/) with [`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) and [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/).

Comment: I think I need to populate field likers to compare objectid's working on it now

Comment: thanks for suggestions Mikey, I am new to mongoose, didn't know about aggregate

Comment: I would definitely NOT go with the `populate` route as that is more expensive and inefficient in your case. You will be querying posts AND all the associated users for each post. All you care about is comparing the ObjectIds.

Comment: I think post.likers.map(String) will work for me thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I was saving the wrong id to the likers array, Doh